# Count repeated values from json data using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

i want to count the total number of browser entries based on the browser values.

ie,what i mean is in the following `json` data i want to count total `"IE8"` and `"FF20`" and `"GC23"`
i want to print

```
var ie =2
var gc =1
var ff =3
```

how it is possible

```
serverResult.forEach(function (lists) {
alert(JSON.stringify(lists))
//it outputs the following data
{ "jobid" : "86", "browser" : "IE8", "_id" : ObjectId("524a7fe53d62ccac12000004") }
{ "jobid" : "34", "browser" : "FF20", "_id" : ObjectId("524a7feb3d62ccac12000005") }
{ "jobid" : "4", "browser" : "IE8", "_id" : ObjectId("524a7ffd3d62ccac12000006") }
{ "jobid" : "34", "browser" : "FF20", "_id" : ObjectId("524a801c3d62ccac12000007") }
{ "jobid" : "4", "browser" : "GC23", "_id" : ObjectId("524a80343d62ccac12000008") }
{ "jobid" : "4", "browser" : "FF20", "_id" : ObjectId("524a84fea6af63fb12000001") }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var browsers = {};
for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
  var currentBrowser = lists[i].browser;
  if (undefined != browsers[currentBrowser]) {
    browsers[currentBrowser]++;       
  }
  else {
    browsers[currentBrowser] = 1;
  }
}
```

AND if you want to display results :

```
for (var browser in browsers) {
   console.log(browser + ' found ' + browsers[browser] + ' times');
}
```

Using an object permits to store other browsers than IE, GC and FF.